# Is there a way to reserve some RAM for a process to prevent it from becoming unresponsive?

Tags: linux, memory-management

I would like to have a text terminal remain responsive, even if any rogue application tries to allocate the whole RAM.

The terminal's child processes should be allowed to use this reserved RAM as well.

Is possible to reserve RAM for a process and its children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux kernel [Control Groups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt) is what you are looking for. With cgroups, you can limit the amount of resources certain processes can use, including memory. So in your case, you would create at least 2 cgroups. One would limit the memory access to all processes on the system to maybe 90% of your total RAM. Then the second one would have access to all the RAM. You would put your terminal process in the second cgroup. There are plenty of resources on the web that cover how to configure your cgroups and it depends somewhat on your particular distribution and kernel version.

Another, simpler option is to just disable swap on your machine. The "unresponsiveness" that you observe is your OS using the swap space. When you disable it, the oom_killer will terminate the process that is hogging all the memory so the system does not appear to hang.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution with swapping and oom_killer isn't good choice in many cases but Control Groups sounds great.

Comment: This solution is not feasible in real systems where you have more than two processes running.